# docker how to commit but exclude directory from image

Tags: docker

I have running docker container and I want to commit the changes on that container, but the size of one of the directories is very huge and I want to exclude it from the snapshot.

How to commit changes on that container while excluding a directory from that image?

Comment: What's exactly your case? I'm afraid you cannot exclude easily a folder directly, but If you know that folder previously you can mount it as a volume, and in that way it will be excluded when committing.

Comment: this folder contain the recorded videos and it is very large. But for backup I don't need this folder. So now how to mount volume to a running container, maybe I can change the video path to use the volume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Container's volumes won't be saved when you commit a container as an image. So you can take advanced of this to exclude a folder (volume) from the snapshot. For example, suppose you want to exclude dir `/my-videos` from your image when committing. You can run your container mounting `/my-videos` as a volume:

`docker run -i -t -v /my-videos my_container /bin/bash`

or you mount a host's folder in container's `/my-videos`:

`docker run -i -t -v /home/user/videos:/my-videos my_container /bin/bash`